# How to create a large sample database?

Tags: database

I have few sample databases but they are quite small in size. I want to create a database with records upto 50GB. I want to learn many aspects of the database and also want to test our application's performance against it.

How to gather random data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of sources on the internet allow you to download their content, and it often reaches into the 10's or 100's of GB. Two that I can think of off the top of my head are:

- Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download)
- StackOverflow (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/)

Though these dumps are in XML, it's easily imported into an empty database by any modern RDBMS. A number of other sites have dumps as well, especially wiki-ish sites (like both of these examples).

Answer (score 2):

Just script a lot of appropriate inserts with randomised data.

I can't be any more specific as you tell us nothing about your database.

Comment: What else you want to know?

Comment: How about the database you're using!

Answer (score 1):

You can use some "Faker" APIs like this one :
http://faker.rubyforge.org/

Or if you want real data, you can gather it from internet, some months ago I needed real data for tests, I've made a IRC bot that log all the messages on the Top 10 channels on Freenode and let it run 24h24 for many weeks, that gave me lot of data (~1 million rows) :)